# Windows' "Change Display Settings" Menu has the correct resolution for my monitor available, but it isn't "Recommended" and doesn't function

Tags: windows

I am using DVI and a Dell 3007WFP monitor which should be able to display at 2,560x1,600. However, Windows defaults to 1280x800, and puts "(Recommended)" next to 1,280x800 in the resolution menu. When I select any higher resolution the monitor glitches out, displaying flickering colored bars and stripes.

Answer (score -1):

This monitor requires a Dual Link DVI cable, which is backwards compatible but has more pins for higher resolution. Once I used the correct cable, the monitor worked fine. Weirdly, with the correct cable Windows still recommends 1280x800, but higher resolutions work fine.